# How to bind DataGrid to a second-level property of a data source?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, properties

Suppose you write up code for a class `Person` whose properties are composed of primitive types **and** a class `Address` whose properties are all primitive types. You put multiple `Person` objects in an `ObservableCollection` and you want to bind it to a DataGrid. The properties with primitive types will display normally, but the property `Address`, that is a class composed of primitive types, will just display "(Collection)".

I found a [solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2007/01/19/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-column-to-a-second-level-property-of-a-data-source.aspx) to this problem while googling, but it seems like a lot of work for a little functionality. The solution I found was for `DataGridView` and it was dated for 2007. Is there an easier way now that we can use WPF and `DataGrid` or is it just as difficult?

**Example code:**

```
class Person
{
    private string id;
    private string name;
    private Address homeAddr;

    public string ID
    {
            get { return id;}
            set { id = value;}
    }

    public string Name
    {
            get { return name;}
            set { name = value;}
    }

    public Address HomeAddr
    {
            get { return homeAddr;}
            set { homeAddr = value;}
    }
}

class Address
{
    private string cityname;
    private string postcode;

    public string CityName
    {
        get { return cityname;}
        set { cityname = value;}
    }

    public string PostCode
    {
        get { return postcode;}
        set { postcode = value;}
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want Address to be displayed? PostCode and City in a column each or a custom cell to hold both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HomeAddr.CityName}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HomeAddr.PostCode}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't add the Address directly to your DataGrid column is because that column expects a primitive type and you send an "Address" type object.
To fix this, you must create a Converter that transforms your Address object into a primitive type, like a string.

First add your converter in the Resource Dictionary

```
<src:AddressToStringConverter x:Key="AddressToStringConverter" />
```

and afterwards use it in your grid

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id }"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HomeAddr, Converter={StaticResource AddressToStringConverter}}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here you can find out more about converters : http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: or you could use `DataGridTemplateColumn` and define appropriate `DataTemplate`